# Сохранить данные в View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload

Имеется PartialView, в котором есть кнопка, при клике которой выполняется отображение модального окна с помощью ajax

```
<div id="Dialog" class="modal fade">
<div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div></div>

@Html.ActionLink("Загрузить фото", "LoadPhoto", null, new { @class = "my-button-2", @id = "loadphoto" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("#loadphoto").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get(this.href, function (data) {
                $('#dialogContent').html(data);
                $('#Dialog').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
```

_LoadPhoto.cshtml

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" area-hidden="true">X</button>
    <p>Загрузите фото:</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <label for="file">Выберите фото:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
    }
</div>
```

После Post-метод

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(
                                   Server.MapPath("~/images"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);

            // save the image path path to the database or you can send image
            // directly to database
            // in-case if you want to store byte[] ie. for DB
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            }

        }
        // after successfully uploading redirect the user
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Все это стянуто с англо-стека.

**Вопрос**: Как или куда сохранить загруженный файл в виде `byte[]`, чтобы потом использовать на странице, из которой был вызов?

Вызов был из страницы создания модели. Т.е. после загрузки картинки в редактируемой модели свойство photo заполнится значением `byte[]`, которое загрузили.

На всякий случай модель

```
public class Employee
{
    ...
    public virtual ManInfo ManInfo { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class ManInfo
{
    ...
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Где хранить byte[] array зависит от вашего приложения. Можно сохранить в базе данных, можно - во временный файл. Главное установить для файла идентификатор, по которому можно найти при отображении. Для зарегистрированного пользователя это может быть код пользователя, для анонимного - анонимный идентификатор.

Comment: Немного не понял вас.
Данный массив мне необходимо использовать в другом методе.
Но следует учесть, что метод с загрузкой файла может быть пропущен.

Попробовал хранить массив на уровне класса - зануляется почему-то.

Comment: Если вы передаете byte[] как параметр в одном запросе к веб-серверу, то информация не пропадет. Если вы говорите про использование параметра между обращениями к веб-серверу, то массив необходимо сохранять в промежуточное хранилище. При каждом обращении объект контроллера заново создается, поэтому у вас "зануляется" массив на уровне класса. Самая близкая альтернатива - переменная сессии.

Comment: В принципе я так и предполагал.
За время, прошедшее с момента вопроса, я немного изменил структуру и теперь выбранный файл необходимо передать с помощью jquery в ajax-запросе в post-метод контроллера, чтобы запиисать данные в бд. Проблема состоит в том, что у меня имеется `<input type="file"/>`, в котором выбран файл. по клику нужно его отправить (валидация размеров уже настроена и функционирует)